# Огонь или только режим?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Можно ли *"готовить на слабом огне", "делать маленький огонь"* не на газовой плите, не в печке и не на костре, а на плите с режимами без реального огня? Допустимо ли продолжать использовать слово *"огонь"* по аналогии с готовкой на настоящем огне?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть случаи, когда такая "огневая" условность вполне допустима, например в кулинарном рецепте с приготовлением на *плите* как таковой. У одной хозяйки она газовая, у другой индукционная, у третьей - и вовсе электроплитка. Ни в одном из этих случаев (в отличие от микроволновой печи, для который все рецепты другие, и духовки, для которой несложно указать температуру выпекания) нет объективных критериев степени нагрева (у разных электроплит разные условные деления или цифры для одной и той же мощности и т. п.). Однако любая хозяйка знает, что молоко кипятить нужно "на малом огне" (иначе оно убежит), и легко создаст такой режим на привычной для себя плите. То же и с "большим (сильным) огнём" - можно ориентироваться на бурное кипение или шипение масла в сковороде, скорректировав рекомендацию под тот же результат на привычной плите.

Было бы странно автору рецепта перечислять названия режимов или указывать количество высвечиваемых цифр для разных моделей плит - мне это напоминает чудаковатую рекламу в петербургском метро: в длинной старой инструкции по безопасности слово "эскалатор", встречавшееся десятка полтора раз, заменили сочетанием "эскалатор и траволатор" во всех мыслимых падежах - просто потому, что в метро появился один единственный "траволатор" (горизонтальный эскалатор) между частями станции, которого большинство горожан в глаза не видели, но теперь подолгу выслушивают упражнения диктора в склонении экзотического словосочетания.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот и я писал собственный рецепт харчо, и мне было очень удобно воспользоваться этой огневой условностью (очень понравилось выражение! ^_^). Да, чего только не придумают из боязни, что кто-то может придраться к формулировке... Мне кажется, вначале не "если случаи", а "есть", правильно?

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, нужно всё называть своими именами, если нет огня, то это просто нагрев, температурный режим: *готовить на плите с малой величиной нагрева, при готовке использовать (выставить) минимальный (средний, максимальный) температурный режим, не допускать чрезмерного нагрева тэнов.*

При этом домохозяйки в быту, конечно, могут использовать и слово огонь - это такая стилистическая вольность устной речи, а в письменной всё же нужно идти в ногу со временем.

Comment: *При этом домохозяйки в быту...* А если готовит мужчина?)) Например я. Ведь тоже могу позволить себе эту вольность?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, ну конечно, можете. )))